# How to print elements with same Xpath below same column (same header)

Tags: ruby, xpath

I'm trying to parse an XML file with REXML on Ruby.

What I want is print all values and the corresponding element name as header. The issue I have
is that some nodes have child elements that appear repeated and have the same Xpath, so for those 
elements I want to printing in the same column. Then for the small sample below, the output desired
for the elements of Node_XX would be:

Output I'm looking for:

```
RepVal|YurVal|CD_val|HJY_val|CD_SubA|CD_SubB
MTSJ|AB01-J|45|01|87|12
||34|11|43|62
```

What I have so far is the code below, but I don´t know how to do in order repeated 
elements be printed in the same column.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Code I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

xmldoc = Document.new File.new("input.xml")

arr_H_Xpath = [] # Array to store only once all Xpath´s (without Xpath repeated)
arr_H_Values = [] # Array for headers (each child element´s name)
arr_Values = [] # Values of each child element.

xmldoc.elements.each("//Node_XYZ") {|element| 
    element.each_recursive do |child| 
        if (child.has_text? && child.text =~ /^[[:alnum:]]/) && !arr_H_Xpath.include?(child.xpath.gsub(/\[.\]/,"")) # Check if element has text and Xpath is stored in arr_H_Xpath.
            arr_H_Xpath << child.xpath.gsub(/\[.\]/,"") #Remove the [..] for repeated XPaths
            arr_H_Values << child.xpath.gsub(/\/\w.*\//,"") #Get only name of child element to use it as header
            arr_Values << child.text
        end
         print arr_H_Values + "|"
         arr_H_Values.clear
    end 
    puts arr_Values.join("|")
}
```

The input.xml is:

```
<TopNode>
 <NodeX>
  <Node_XX>
    <RepCD_valm>
      <RepVal>MTSJ</RepVal>
    </RepCD_valm>
    <RepCD_yur>
      <Yur>
        <YurVal>AB01-J</YurVal>
      </Yur>    
    </RepCD_yur>
    <CodesDif>
      <CD_Ranges>
        <CD_val>45</CD_val>
        <HJY_val>01</HJY_val>
        <CD_Sub>
          <CD_SubA>87</CD_SubA>
          <CD_SubB>12</CD_SubB>
        </CD_Sub>
      </CD_Ranges>
    </CodesDif>
    <CodesDif>
      <CD_Ranges>
        <CD_val>34</CD_val>
        <HJY_val>11</HJY_val>
        <CD_Sub>
          <CD_SubA>43</CD_SubA>
          <CD_SubB>62</CD_SubB>
        </CD_Sub>
      </CD_Ranges>
    </CodesDif>
  </Node_XX>
  <Node_XY>
    ....
    ....
    ....
  </Node_XY>
 </NodeX>
</TopNode>
```

Comment: Why REXML rather than Nokogiri?

Comment: What determines when you want a new row? A new `<CodesDif>` or `<CD_Ranges>` element?

Comment: Hello Mark,

I only began to try with REXML, since is the first XML parsing package I saw for ruby. If you know that Nokogiri is better for this task is ok :)
The first row would be completed, when be printed the values of the first child element for each header( the header is element name for non repeated XPath).

Then I for the same XPath, is matched more than one child element, I want to printing below the same column(header) and for the other  child 
elements print blank value "". I hope make sense.

Thanks for the help

Comment: More clear: The first row would be completed when be printed the values of the first child element for each header(header is child element´s name for all 
non repeated XPath´s). If one element is repeated 3 times, then, 3 Xpath appear. So take that XPath only once. Then if one XPath matches more 
than one child element value, I want to print each value below the same column(header) and print blank "" for the others child elements.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve your problem. It is probably a little unusual, but I was experimenting. :)

First, I chose a data structure that can store the headers as keys and multiple values per key to represent the additional row(s) of data: a MultiMap. It is like a hash with multiple keys.

With the multimap, you can store the elements as key-value pairs:

```
data = Multimap.new

doc.xpath('//RepVal|//YurVal|//CD_val|//HJY_val|//CD_SubA|//CD_SubB').each do |elem|
   data[elem.name] = elem.inner_text
end
```

The content of `data` is:

```
  {"RepVal"=>["MTSJ"],
   "YurVal"=>["AB01-J"],
   "CD_val"=>["45", "34"],
   "HJY_val"=>["01", "11"],
   "CD_SubA"=>["87", "43"],
   "CD_SubB"=>["12", "62"]}
```

As you can see, this was a simple way to collect all the information you need to create your table. Now it is just a matter of transforming it to your pipe-delimited format. For this, or any delimited format, I recommend using `CSV`:

```
out = CSV.generate({col_sep: "|"}) do |csv|
  columns = data.keys.to_a.uniq
  csv << columns
  while !data.values.empty? do
    csv << columns.map { |col| data[col].shift }
  end
end
```

The output is:

```
RepVal|YurVal|CD_val|HJY_val|CD_SubA|CD_SubB
MTSJ|AB01-J|45|01|87|12
||34|11|43|62
```

Explanation:

`CSV.generate` creates a string. If you wanted to create an output file directly, use `CSV.open` instead. See the [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) for more information. I added the `col_sep` option to delimit with a pipe character instead of the default of a comma.

Getting a list of columns would just be the keys if `data` was a hash. But since it is a Multimap which will repeat key names, I have to call `.to_a.uniq` on it. Then I add them to the output using `csv << columns`.

In order to create the second row (and any subsequent rows), we slice down and get the *first* value for each key of `data`. That's what the `data[col].shift` does: it actually removes the first value from each value in `data`. The loop is in place to keep going as long as there are more values (more rows).

Comment: I'm trying and I've installed gem multimap, but I get error  
  
    ./parse_xml_stackoverflow.rb:8:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Multimap (NameError)  
   
I attemptted something similar, defining an array with all Xpath explicitly written, but in real file there are more than 200
Xpath (headers) to print and the script takes between 30 sec to 10 min). When the xpath are stored dynamically within
the script, the performance speed is much better (3 seconds to finish).
  
Is it possible to dynamically get the unique xpath´s to work with your code?  
Your code is Nokogiri's based or REXML?

Comment: At the top of the code, you'll need `require 'nokogiri'` and `require 'multimap'`.

Comment: With that many headers, this solution will not be optimal. If you know the exact path to each header (so you don't have to use the `//` wildcard), it will speed up considerably. How big is the file itself? If it's too big, you may be better off not using DOM and XPath at all and instead use Nokogiri's SAX or Reader interfaces.

Comment: Hello Mark, Thanks for the help. Please see my own answer, I've updated. I'm not sure, I think you can see it below my original question. The recent update is below the word # Update: #